# SublimeClang OSX Mountain Lion C++11

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, clang

Has anyone got instructions for how to get C++11 working with SublimeClang under OS X mountain lion.

If I use non C++11 libs and code it is happy but as soon as I try to use something like std::shared_ptr it moans.

I am obviously missing something simple and any help would be appreciated.

I have set the additional options also to -std=c++11 so I really have no idea what I am missing.

Blair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X 10.9 Mavericks the following configuration is working for me:

1. Get a working compilation with the OS X provided `clang++` on the command line. Append the `-v` command line option to get a list of the system include directories it uses. For me these were: 
   `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include`
2. SublimeClang adds its own include files by default, which on my system were outdated. Set this preference for SublimeClang: `"dont_prepend_clang_includes": true`
3. Enable C++11 in the SublimeClang language options:
   `"additional_language_options":{"c++": ["--std=c++11"]}`

Comment: I updated XCode and it updated Clang to version 6.0 (LLVM 3.5svn). Now SublimeClang is broken. The problem is that /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1 doesn't exist anymore! This means that any standard library has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

It may be too late, but I found how to do it.
This matter is because clang uses headers for gcc-4.2, which is quite old and doesn't support C++11.

To complete C++11 code, you have to get newer gcc and copy the include path it uses.
If you have homebrew, open terminal and type

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc48
```

You can install gcc-4.8 and new libstdc++ with these two lines. Now, create some c++ file and try to use g++-4.8 with -v option.

```
g++-4.8 -v example.cpp
```

-v option tell gcc to show detailed log. In the output, there should be some lines like this.

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1/backward
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
```

These paths are gcc4.8 uses to find headers. Open SublimeClang.sublime-settings--User, and put these paths and "-std=c++11" like this.

```
{
    "options":[
    "-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1",
    "-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1",
    "-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1/backward",
    "-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/include",
    "-I/usr/local/include",
    "-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/include",
    "-I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.1/4.8.1/include-fixed",
    "-I/usr/include",
    "-I/System/Library/Frameworks",
    "-I/Library/Frameworks"
    ],

    "additional_language_options":
    {
        "c++" :[
        "-std=c++11"
        ],
        "c": [],
        "objc": [],
        "objc++": []
    }
}
```

I could do it this way.

It won't be so different if you don't use homebrew.

Comment: As an alternative I assume you could use libc++ included with OS X rather than getting an updated libstdc++. libc++ is OS X's new implementation of the C++11 standard library.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but when I use libc++, there is __1 namespace (I know this namespace is for declaring that using libc++ instead of libstdc++) in the complete suggestion and I couldn't find out how to remove it. @bames53